# golang: function with variadic number of interface arguments

Tags: go, interface, variadic

I have trouble finding answer to the following question.

I have an interface and a struct that implements it.

```golang
type InterfaceA interface {
   DoA()
}

type ImplementsA struct {}

func (a ImplementsA) DoA() {
   fmt.Println("do A")
}
```

The question is: why can't I use a slice of ImplementsA to pass it to a function, that expects a variadic number of InterfaceA arguments?

```golang
func UsesVariadicNumberOfA(as ...InterfaceA) {
    for _, a := range as {
        a.DoA()
    }
}

func main() {
    a1 := ImplementsA{}
    a2 := ImplementsA{}
    as := []ImplementsA{a1, a2}
    
    // this does not compile, with "cannot use as (variable of type []ImplementsA) as []InterfaceA [...]"
    UsesVariadicNumberOfA(as...)

    // this works, of course
    ais := []InterfaceA{a1, a2}
    UsesVariadicNumberOfA(ais...)
}
```

Comment: "why can't I use a slice of ImplementsA to pass it to a function, that expects a variadic number of InterfaceA arguments?" Because Go's type system has neither co- no contravaraiance. See also https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface. 100% duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

The error message of compiler just say the answer.

Notice that the parameter type of this function is ***InterfaceA***

```go
func UsesVariadicNumberOfA(as ...InterfaceA) {
    for _, a := range as {
        a.DoA()
    }
}
```

But use put the type of ***ImplementsA*** in it

```go
// type of as is []ImplementsA !!
UsesVariadicNumberOfA(as...)
```

just write another function and its parameter type is ***ImplementsA*** will solve this problem.

Comment: See also https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface.

Comment: BWbwchen, that is not a typo. InterfaceA is an interface which is implemented by ImplementsA, so if it would be just a simple single argument and not variadic it would work fine.

If I have a function with signature:
func UsesSingleA(a InterfaceA) {...}

...and would use it with the _a1_ variable used in the main like this:
UsesSingleA(a1)

it would work perfectly.

The answer to my question is what @bcmills linked. Thanks for that, @bcmills!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my fault, @bcmills and Máté-Pusztai !